# How to get react element from event.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have attached an event listener to the parent element to listen for a non-synthetic-event and I wonder if there is a nice way to get reference to the component which triggers the event to use it's properties

I need to postpone the rendering of `item.component` until the `nonSyntheticEvent` occurs

```
const items = [
  {
    name: "click me",
    component: function First() {
      return <strong>asd</strong>;
    }
  },
  {
    name: "click me 2",
    component: function Second() {
      return <b>oasd</b>;
    }
  }
];

class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.el.addEventListener("nonSyntheticEvent", event =>
      this.nonSyntheticEventHandler(event)
    );
  }

  nonSyntheticEventHandler(event) {

    // how to get reference to item
    // from event.target to render it's item.component

    const el = React.createElement(item.component);
    ReactDOM.render(el, event.target);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => { this.el = ref; }}>
        {this.props.items.map(item => <Child {...item} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

<Component items={items} />
```

Comment: You could try attaching a reverse reference in the ref function, maybe? `ref={ref => { this.el = ref; ref.reactComponent = this }}`. Seems very hacky, though.

Comment: It should be handled with refs, not necessarily as suggested above but somehow. What's your case exactly? What is this event and why should div be replaced with its own child? There may be much less complicated ways to achieve a similar thing, depending on what should the result look like.

Comment: It's a *select* event, native for Apple TV TVML applications and the doc will not be replaced by it's child, I was trying to simplify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With React 16.3 `React.createRef()` is introduced which can be used in `Component` to create reference before the `Child` component is rendered.

for example in `Component.constructor` a reference to each child can be created in the state

```
this.state = {
  items: items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    reference: React.createRef()
  }))
};
```

and then in the Child component can be used from props:

```
function Child(props){
  return (
    <div ref={props.reference}>
      <span>{props.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then in the `nonSyntheticEventHandler` the item can be obtained like so:

```
const found = this.state.items.find(item => {
  return item.reference.current === event.target;
});
```

working example in [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/2xlvl161ny)